# IIS responding to single request with two responses

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-6, windows-server-2003, httphandler

We have a user making a POST to our webserver (windows server 2003, IIS 6). They get the full response from our webapp, but then IIS also responds with a "400 Bad Request". No other information is provided (yes I have friendly errors turned off).

At first, I thought maybe it was some middleware injecting a response in there. However, I was able to find the following in the HTTPSys error logs which confirms that it is coming from our server:

2013-08-09 23:36:40  11901  80 HTTP/0.0 Unparsed - 400 - BadRequest -

There are a whole slew of these errors piling up, and I have no idea why. Unparsed doesn't really tell me anything, so I don't have much to go on. I was able to get them to produce a wireshark trace, which shows that we are indeed responding with the full correct response and then appending a 400 bad request response. I copied their request EXACTLY from wireshark and tried it from my machine and of course, I can't reproduce it (I get the one valid response back).

So I am completely unable to reproduce the "Unparsed" error, I WAS however able to get two responses back from one request. I intentionally broke the line endings between the request headers and body and I got back a full correct response followed by "Bad Request (Invalid Verb)".

Two questions

1) Does anyone have any ideas as to how to produce an "Unparsed" error in HTTPsys logs? Any thoughts on how I might go about reproducing this?

2) WHY is IIS responding to a single request with two responses? Is that normal behavior, or indicative of a configuration error?

Thanks for anyone willing to offer help on this terrible headache!

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer my own question here because I wouldn't wish this pain upon anyone else.

It turned out their POST had a slight error in content-length, I am thinking it wasn't including the final "\r\n" but whatever it is the count ended up being short by 2.

The reason this never showed up when I copied the exact request and sent it from my machine was that I wasn't properly closing the connection. For some reason, closing the connection with a FIN actually makes the difference and causes the 400 Bad Request.

Not sure why this happens, maybe the extra chars sent in the initial request are somehow read when the FIN comes? I don't know, but there you have it. Fix the content-length and the pain goes away.